# Writing a conditional within an each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of Twilio Recording SIDs that I'm using to generate links to a users call recording.  When I use them in a table and the SID is empty, I'd like to print "No Recording".

```
<tr>
  <% @empty_check.each do |rec| %>
      <% if rec.empty? %>
      <td><%= "No Recording" %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td><%=link_to 'listen', "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{@account_sid}/Recordings/" + rec, :target => "_blank"%></td> 
       <% end %>  
  <% end %>    
 </tr>
```

Even though I know one of the values in that given array is empty, it still prints the `else` code.

Furthermore, when I do something like this

```
@empty_check.each {|m| print m.empty?}
falsefalsefalsefalsetruefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalsefalse
```

I see a `true` value.

What am I missing in that conditional above that its not recognizing the empty value?

**Update

The `@empty_check` example was me trying to isolate what I thought was the problem and debugging.

Here is the actual controller code:

```
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account
@calls = @subaccount.calls
@callslist = @calls.list({:page_size => @page_size, :page => @page, :"start_time>" =>       @start_date, :"start_time<" => @end_date})
@callsids = @callslist.map {|m| m.parent_call_sid}.compact
```

And the actual view code:

```
<% @callsids.each do |c| %>

   <tr>
     <% @call = @calls.get(c) %>
     <td><%= Date.parse(@call.date_created).strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></td>
     <td><%= Time.parse(@call.start_time).strftime("%I:%M%P") %></td>
     <td><%= @call.from %></td>
     <td><%= @call.to %></td>
     <td><%= ChronicDuration.output(@call.duration.to_i, :format => :short) %></td>
     <% @recording = @recordings.get(c) %>
     <% @calls.get(@call.sid).recordings.list.each do |rec| %>
       <% if rec.sid.empty? %>
        <td><%= "No Recording" %></td>
       <% else %>
        <td><%=link_to 'listen', "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#{@account_sid}/Recordings/" + rec.sid, :target => "_blank"%></td> 
       <% end %>  
      <% end %>               
    </tr>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your view code, aside from an unnecessary usage of embedded ruby to print "No Recording". You can just do `<td>No Recording</td>` there. Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are accessing the same variable in your print test and the main code block? Try outputting the value of `@empty_check` within the template just before the test you are interested in (optionally in a comment).

---

Update to respond to updated question:

```
<% @calls.get(@call.sid).recordings.list.each do |rec| %>
```

Isn't that line the issue? If the call has no recordings the whole block will be skipped so it will never write "No recordings.". I'm making guesses about the Twilio API but are you sure that recording objects are returned that have a `sid` value that returns true for `.empty?`

Couldn't the above line be simplified to:

```
<% @calls.get(c).recordings.list.each do |rec| %>
```

or even:

```
<% @call.recordings.list.each do |rec| %>
```

And don't you want to (and try this with the API first) do the `if xxx.empty?` outside of the each in this case.

```
<% reclist = @call.recordings.list %>
<% if reclist.empty? %>
  <td><%= "No Recording" %></td>
<% else %>
  <% reclist.each do |rec| %>
    <td><%=link_to 'listen', "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#{@account_sid}/Recordings/" + rec.sid, :target => "_blank"%></td> 
  <% end %>               
 <% end %>
```

---

Simplified version added after answer accepted. Pulls the  tag outside the if (and the each) so that all the links go together in the same table cell if there are multiple recordings for the call.

```
<% reclist = @call.recordings.list %>
<td>
<% if reclist.empty? %>
  No Recording
<% else %>
  <% reclist.each do |rec| %>
    <%=link_to 'listen', "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#{@account_sid}/Recordings/" + rec.sid, :target => "_blank"%> 
  <% end %>               
 <% end %>
 </td>
```

Comment: I appreciate the heads up, good thought, but just an oversight :)  Fixed.

Comment: You got it, thank you Joseph!  I also appreciate the extra explanation, I understand why the code I have was not working now.